# Cannot concat sh command with variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want run `kubectl` command in my `jenkins pipeline` with variables.

My code :

```
def POD_FULL_NAME = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=test -o name'
POD_FULL_NAME = POD_FULL_NAME.tokenize('/')
def POD_NAME = POD_FULL_NAME[1]
sh """kubectl exec -it ${POD_NAME} -n ci npm test"""
```

But when I try this I have :

```
kubectl exec -it test
```

without end of command.

`test` is my pod name

Can you explain me ?

Comment: Try something like that:

sh("kubectl exec -it ${POD_NAME} -n ci npm test")

I think doubling the quoutes could mess the script line.

Comment: Can you try `sh """kubectl exec -it -n ci ${POD_NAME} -- npm test"""`

Comment: What is the value of  POD_FULL_NAME after first sh command?